# fabric 1.0 install chain code fails: endorser client failed to connect to org1.example.com:7051

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-chaincode

I am using fabric 1.0 and getting the following error when install chaincode into org1.example.com

the command I use to install chaincode is:

```
docker exec cli peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1 -p github.com/chaincode/sacc
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Error: error getting endorser client for install: endorser client failed to connect to org1.example.com:7051: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp: lookup org1.example.com on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host"
```

I have already do the ip to domain mapping at /etc/hosts

any idea why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The chaincode language tag is missing in the installation command. If it is a node js chaincode then add `-l node` or if go language then add `-l go` like this.

```
docker exec cli peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -l node -p github.com/chaincode/sacc
```